# List all deployments from Jboss using either JMX or JNDI

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, jmx

Is there a way to get a list of all deployments on a Jboss 6.0 
implemented in Java either using JMX (ServerMBean) or JNDI?

Comment: Use `jconsole` if you find there an operation which returns the deployments -> yes there is a way to get it via JMX, otherwise no. What about using `jboss-cli` for such kind of information?

Comment: I need to code this in java, but I cant figure out the ObjectName or what the resulting Bean class is

Comment: Hope this could be in a form of


`Set<ObjectInstance> mBeans = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().queryMBeans(new ObjectName("org.jboss.admin:type=Application,name=*"), null);
         for (ObjectInstance objectInstance : mBeans) {
          services.add(JMX.newMXBeanProxy(server, objectInstance.getObjectName(), ApplicationMXBean.class));
         }`

Comment: What I need is a list of jar, war and ear files deployed.

Answer (score 0):

On Wildfly 9.0.1.Final the code looks like this:

```
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 9990;
    String urlString = System.getProperty("jmx.service.url","service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://" + host + ":" + port);
    JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(urlString);
    JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, null);
    MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
    ObjectName name = new ObjectName("jboss.modules:type=ModuleLoader,name=*");
    Set<ObjectInstance> objectInstances = connection.queryMBeans(name, null);
    for (ObjectInstance objectInstance : objectInstances) {
        if (objectInstance.getObjectName().getCanonicalName().contains("ServiceModuleLoader")) {
            System.out.println("invoking method on " + objectInstance.getObjectName());
            Object dumpAllModuleInformation = connection.invoke(objectInstance.getObjectName(), "dumpAllModuleInformation", new Object[]{}, new String[]{});
            System.out.println(dumpAllModuleInformation);
        }
    }
    jmxConnector.close();
```

Maybe you can adapt this to JBoss 6. On Wildfly 9.0.1.Finale this outputs:

```
Module deployment.stackoverflow-jboss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main
    Class loader: ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.stackoverflow-jboss-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    Resource Loaders:
        Loader Type: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.VFSResourceLoader
        Paths:

            META-INF
            META-INF/maven
            META-INF/maven/stackoverflow-jboss
```